# Phantom transaction expired error on using durable nonce

Tags: solana-wallet-adapter, phantom

phantom shows transaction expired error when using durable nonces . Looks like phantom isnt recognising the durable nonce in the recent blockhash and instead considering it as an old blockhash, clicking ignore warning and continue works but its super annoying for the users. Is there a workaround to this ?

Comment: A quick search on the Phantom support page showed no results for "nonce", which makes me think they just might not support it. You should check with them directly to be sure though